# Can I rollback apt-upgrade from tar backup?

Tags: apt, server, updates, tar

I recently made apt-upgrade which broke something in my system that I cannot identify. I have a .tar backup of the whole filesystem that I made recently. Is there a way to use this backup to rollback my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a backup of the whole filesystem (including apt/dpkg state database), then yes, restoring that backup should roll back your upgrades. However, there is a small possibility that some new files added by the upgrade (that didn't exist previously and so are not present in your backup) can still break something. In that case you need to identify the files that are not present in your backup and delete them.

Comment: This worked for me, I suupose I was lucky enough for upgrade to now have added new files as you mentioned.